# Apache redirect from any subdirectory to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I would like to redirect user from any subdirectory like

```
example.com/abc
example.com/xyz/abc
example.com/123/456/789
```

to the content of root directory, but I would want this link to stay like that, so I can read it with JavaScript. So user types example.com/xyz, presses enter, is presented with whatever is in root catalog, but in address field he still sees *example.com/xyz*.

Comment: It looks like you have tacked on a second question at the bottom. It might be better for you to submit that separately. Also can you include details about what you've already tried and how it is not working?

Comment: I removed this second question for now, thanks for advice. As for what I already tried to do - multiple RewriteCond/RewriteRule commands. However all of them didn't preserve URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# route to landing page
RewriteRule . / [L]
```

However keep in mind that you're creating duplicate content.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. These two RewriteCond rules were what I was missing whole time. And I apologize if this question was asked before - I searched for it both here and in google.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource